Problem when using EditorJS image upload with uploadthing v5.x.x ++
Im using EditorJs to create a post having img and uploadthing to store that img. However, i cant upload image if using uploadthing version higher than 4.x.x (which is no more supported), every time i try to upload a image i got:
Image Tool: uploading failed because of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

my EditorJS img config:
const ImageTool = (await import('@editorjs/image')).default;
image: {
    class: ImageTool,
        config: {
        uploader: {
            uploadByFile: async (file: File) => {
                const res = await uploadFiles([file], 'imageUploader');
                console.log(res)
                return {
                    success: 1,
                    // file: { url: res[0].fileUrl },
                };
            },
        },
    },
},

The console.log(res) cant be reached
file log:
enter image description here
I tried to use uploadthing 7.x.x:
my uploadhing.ts:
import type { OurFileRouter } from '~/app/api/uploadthing/core'
import {generateReactHelpers, generateUploadDropzone} from "@uploadthing/react";

export const { uploadFiles } = generateReactHelpers<OurFileRouter>();
export const UploadDropzone = generateUploadDropzone<OurFileRouter>();

my OurFileRouter:
import { createUploadthing, type FileRouter } from 'uploadthing/next-legacy'
import {currentUser} from "~/lib/auth";


const f = createUploadthing()

export const ourFileRouter = {
  imageUploader: f({ image: { maxFileSize: '4MB' } })
    .middleware(async (req) => {
        console.log(req)
      const user = await currentUser()
      if (!user) throw new Error('Unauthorized')
      return { userId: user.id }
    })
    .onUploadComplete(async ({ metadata, file }) => {console.log(file)}),
} satisfies FileRouter

export type OurFileRouter = typeof ourFileRouter

route:
import { createRouteHandler } from 'uploadthing/next';

import { ourFileRouter } from './core';

const handler = createRouteHandler({
  router: ourFileRouter
});
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

but didnt solve the problem
